# Matlab: how to plot a text in 3D

Tags: matlab

text(x,y,z,'text') works in 3D space however it is not 3D. Is there a way to plot a simple 3D text in matlab, something as simple as this:
[image: the text]

I do not need shadowing or rendering, only to be able to add 3rd dimension to the text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to do this using text. You would have to have an *image* of the text and [texture map](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/visualize/f0-18164.html#f0-9250) the 2-D image onto a [3-D surface](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/surf.html). By default graphics are rendered in the axes using an orthographic projection, so to create perspective as you have in your image above you would have to either:

1. Artificially create it by shrinking the length of one side of the surface on which the image is texture-mapped.
2. [Adjust the view projection of the axes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/visualize/f4-22650.html).

Here is some sample code to illustrate the above. I'll start by creating a sample text image:

```
hFigure = figure('Color', 'w', ...        %# Create a figure window
                 'MenuBar', 'none', ...
                 'ToolBar', 'none');
hText = uicontrol('Parent', hFigure, ...  %# Create a text object
                  'Style', 'text', ...
                  'String', 'PHOTOSHOP', ...
                  'BackgroundColor', 'w', ...
                  'ForegroundColor', 'r', ...
                  'FontSize', 50, ...
                  'FontWeight', 'bold');
set([hText hFigure], 'Pos', get(hText, 'Extent'));  %# Adjust the sizes of the
                                                    %#   text and figure
imageData = getframe(hFigure);  %# Save the figure as an image frame
delete(hFigure);
textImage = imageData.cdata;  %# Get the RGB image of the text
```

Now that we have an image of the text we want, here is how you can texture map it on a 3-D surface and adjust the view projection:

```
surf([0 1; 0 1], [1 0; 1 0], [1 1; 0 0], ...
     'FaceColor', 'texturemap', 'CData', textImage);
set(gca, 'Projection', 'perspective', 'CameraViewAngle', 45, ...
    'CameraPosition', [0.5 -1 0.5], 'Visible', 'off');
```

And here's the resulting image:

[image]