# How to prevent an object from being illuminated by camlight in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, graphics, shadow, light

*[Hereafter are 4 snippets, one should only be interested in reading the two first ones. However by copy-pasting all of these, one should be able to launch what I see, although **screenshots are provided at the end**.]*

Hi, by launching this **main.m** :

```
%To see if plotting a tick after setting camlight headlight will leads to
%its background becoming gray or not
%clear all
figure
arrow = arrow3D([0 0 0], [1 1 1], 'r', 0.8, 0.2, 1.5);
set(arrow, 'EdgeColor', 'interp', 'FaceColor', 'interp');
%camlight headlight %might be interesting to uncomment this line
pause(5)
surfaceHandle = rotateAxisTicks('lol','r',10,-0.3,0.5,0.5,1,1,1,0);
pause(5)
camlight headlight
%material(surfaceHandle,'default') %doesn't work
%surfaceHandle1.FaceLighting = 'none' %doesn't work
```

, which uses that function **rotateAxisTicks.m**

```
function surfaceHandle = rotateAxisTicks(str,color,fontsize,zmax,graduSpace,boxHeight,perc,labelNumber,axnumber,thetaInput)
%https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9843048/matlab-how-to-plot-a-text-in-3d
    %zmax : give it a negative value to not overlap the axis
    %graduSpace : space between each graduation, within the projected on [0,1] axis if axis = x||y, OR local (not yet projected on x,y) axis !!
    %boxHeight : width of the boxes depend on how much the axis graduations are refined, so height shouldn't depend on graduSpace
    %perc : if perc = 1 (100%), then the labels are all sticked together with no space inbetween
    %labelNumber : the first tick to be displayed is actually associated to the second graduation (0 can't get several labels)
    %axnumber : out of nbParams, 1 for x, 2 for y, then, from closest to x, to closest to y : 3 to nbParams.
    %thetaInput : (angle around z, from x to the axis) has to be in degree

    %% Seems like there is no way to get rid of the black contouring...
    hFigure = figure(1000);
    set(hFigure,'Color', 'w', ...        % Create a figure window
                     'MenuBar', 'none', ...
                     'ToolBar', 'none');
    hText = uicontrol('Parent', hFigure, ...  % Create a text object
                      'Style', 'text', ...
                      'String', str, ...
                      'BackgroundColor', 'w', ...
                      'ForegroundColor', color, ...
                      'FontSize', fontsize, ...
                      'FontWeight', 'normal');
    set([hText hFigure], 'Pos', get(hText, 'Extent'));  %# Adjust the sizes of the
                                                        %#   text and figure
    imageData = getframe(hFigure);  %# Save the figure as an image frame
    delete(hFigure);
    textImage = imageData.cdata;  %# Get the RGB image of the text

    %% MAKE THE X,Y,Z (text) REVERSE DEPENDING ON AZIMUT VALUE (launch a fig and see on the bottom in real time the azimut value)
    % X or Y or Z(1,1) =  _______
    %                    *       |
    %                    |       |
    %                    |_______|
    % X or Y or Z(1,2) =  _______
    %                    |       *
    %                    |       |
    %                    |_______|
    % X or Y or Z(2,1) =  _______
    %                    |       |
    %                    |       |
    %                    x_______|
    % X or Y or Z(2,2) =  _______
    %                    |       |
    %                    |       |
    %                    |_______x
    if axnumber == 2 %axis = y
        X = [0 0; 0 0];
        Y = [0 perc*graduSpace; 0 perc*graduSpace] + labelNumber*graduSpace - perc*graduSpace/2;
        %(graduSpace/2)/2 to center under the graduation, (1-perc)/2) to
        %additionally shift a bit so that the perc% of graduSpace stay centered
        %under the graduation
    else %I assume axis = x, that I might later rotate if it's not actually x
        X = [0 perc*graduSpace; 0 perc*graduSpace] + labelNumber*graduSpace - perc*graduSpace/2; %+labelNumber*((graduSpace/2)+((1-perc)/2)*graduSpace)
        Y = [0 0; 0 0];
    end
    Z = [zmax zmax; zmax-boxHeight zmax-boxHeight];
    surfaceHandle = surf(X, Y, Z, 'FaceColor', 'texturemap', 'CData', textImage);
    if axnumber > 2
        rotate(surfaceHandle, [0 0 1], thetaInput,[0 0 0]);
    end
end
```

as well as that function **arrow3D.m** :

```
function arrowHandle = arrow3D(pos, deltaValues, colorCode, stemRatio, cylRad, radRatioCone)

% arrowHandle = arrow3D(pos, deltaValues, colorCode, stemRatio) %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% 
%     Used to plot a single 3D arrow with a cylindrical stem and cone arrowhead
%     pos = [X,Y,Z] - spatial location of the starting point of the arrow (end of stem)
%     deltaValues = [QX,QY,QZ] - delta parameters denoting the magnitude of the arrow along the x,y,z-axes (relative to 'pos')
%     colorCode - Color parameters as per the 'surf' command.  For example, 'r', 'red', [1 0 0] are all examples of a red-colored arrow
%     stemRatio - The ratio of the length of the stem in proportion to the arrowhead.  For example, a call of:
%                 arrow3D([0,0,0], [100,0,0] , 'r', 0.82) will produce a red arrow of magnitude 100, with the arrowstem spanning a distance
%                 of 82 (note 0.82 ratio of length 100) while the arrowhead (cone) spans 18.  
% 
%     Example:
%       arrow3D([0,0,0], [4,3,7]);  %---- arrow with default parameters
%       axis equal;
% 
%    Author: Shawn Arseneau
%    Created: September 14, 2006
%    Updated: September 18, 2006
% 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    if nargin<2 || nargin>6    
        error('Incorrect number of inputs to arrow3D');     
    end
    if numel(pos)~=3 || numel(deltaValues)~=3
        error('pos and/or deltaValues is incorrect dimensions (should be three)');
    end
    if nargin<3                 
        colorCode = 'interp';                               
    end
    if nargin<4                 
        stemRatio = 0.75;                                   
    end    

    X = pos(1); %---- with this notation, there is no need to transpose if the user has chosen a row vs col vector
    Y = pos(2);
    Z = pos(3);

    [sphi, stheta, srho] = cart2sph(deltaValues(1), deltaValues(2), deltaValues(3));  

    %******************************************* CYLINDER == STEM *********************************************
    %cylinderRadius = 0.05*srho;
    cylinderRadius = cylRad;
    cylinderLength = srho*stemRatio;
    [CX,CY,CZ] = cylinder(cylinderRadius);
    CZ = CZ.*cylinderLength;    %---- lengthen

    %----- ROTATE CYLINDER
    [row, col] = size(CX);      %---- initial rotation to coincide with X-axis

    newEll = rotatePoints([0 0 -1], [CX(:), CY(:), CZ(:)]); %CX(:) actually reshape the 2xN matrices in a 2N vert vector, by vertically concatenating each column
    CX = reshape(newEll(:,1), row, col);
    CY = reshape(newEll(:,2), row, col);
    CZ = reshape(newEll(:,3), row, col);

    [row, col] = size(CX);    
    newEll = rotatePoints(deltaValues, [CX(:), CY(:), CZ(:)]);
    stemX = reshape(newEll(:,1), row, col);
    stemY = reshape(newEll(:,2), row, col);
    stemZ = reshape(newEll(:,3), row, col);

    %----- TRANSLATE CYLINDER
    stemX = stemX + X;
    stemY = stemY + Y;
    stemZ = stemZ + Z;

    %******************************************* CONE == ARROWHEAD *********************************************
    coneLength = srho*(1-stemRatio);
    coneRadius = cylinderRadius*radRatioCone;
    incr = 100;  %---- Steps of cone increments
    coneincr = coneRadius/incr;
    [coneX, coneY, coneZ] = cylinder(cylinderRadius*2:-coneincr:0);  %---------- CONE 
    coneZ = coneZ.*coneLength;

    %----- ROTATE CONE 
    [row, col] = size(coneX);    
    newEll = rotatePoints([0 0 -1], [coneX(:), coneY(:), coneZ(:)]);
    coneX = reshape(newEll(:,1), row, col);
    coneY = reshape(newEll(:,2), row, col);
    coneZ = reshape(newEll(:,3), row, col);

    newEll = rotatePoints(deltaValues, [coneX(:), coneY(:), coneZ(:)]);
    headX = reshape(newEll(:,1), row, col);
    headY = reshape(newEll(:,2), row, col);
    headZ = reshape(newEll(:,3), row, col);

    %---- TRANSLATE CONE
    V = [0, 0, srho*stemRatio];    %---- centerline for cylinder: the multiplier is to set the cone 'on the rim' of the cylinder
    Vp = rotatePoints([0 0 -1], V);
    Vp = rotatePoints(deltaValues, Vp);
    headX = headX + Vp(1) + X;
    headY = headY + Vp(2) + Y;
    headZ = headZ + Vp(3) + Z;
    %************************************************************************************************************    
    hStem = surf(stemX, stemY, stemZ, 'FaceColor', colorCode, 'EdgeColor', 'none');
    hold on
    hBottStem = fill3(stemX(1,:),stemY(1,:),stemZ(1,:), colorCode, 'EdgeColor', 'none');
    hold on
    hHead = surf(headX, headY, headZ, 'FaceColor', colorCode, 'EdgeColor', 'none');
    hold on
    hBottCone = fill3(headX(1,:),headY(1,:),headZ(1,:), colorCode, 'EdgeColor', 'none');

    if nargout==1   
        arrowHandle = [hStem, hBottStem, hHead, hBottCone]; 
    end
```

which itself uses that function **rotatePoints.m** :

```
function rotatedData = rotatePoints(alignmentVector, originalData)

% rotatedData = rotatePoints(alignmentVector, originalData) %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% 
%     Rotate the 'originalData' in the form of Nx2 or Nx3 about the origin by aligning the x-axis with the alignment vector
% 
%       Rdata = rotatePoints([1,2,-1], [Xpts(:), Ypts(:), Zpts(:)]) - rotate the (X,Y,Z)pts in 3D with respect to the vector [1,2,-1]
% 
%       Rotating using spherical components can be done by first converting using [dX,dY,dZ] = cart2sph(theta, phi, rho);  alignmentVector = [dX,dY,dZ];
% 
% Example:
%   %% Rotate the point [3,4,-7] with respect to the following:
%   %%%% Original associated vector is always [1,0,0]
%   %%%% Calculate the appropriate rotation requested with respect to the x-axis.  For example, if only a rotation about the z-axis is
%   %%%% sought, alignmentVector = [2,1,0] %% Note that the z-component is zero
%   rotData = rotatePoints(alignmentVector, [3,4,-7]);
% 
%     Author: Shawn Arseneau
%     Created: Feb.2, 2006
% 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    alignmentDim = numel(alignmentVector); %number of elements in a matrix
    DOF = size(originalData,2); %---- DOF = Degrees of Freedom (i.e. 2 for two dimensional and 3 for three dimensional data)

    if alignmentDim~=DOF    
        error('Alignment vector does not agree with originalData dimensions');      
    end
    if DOF<2 || DOF>3      
        error('rotatePoints only does rotation in two or three dimensions');        
    end


    if DOF==2  % 2D rotation...        
        [rad_theta, rho] = cart2pol(alignmentVector(1), alignmentVector(2));    
        deg_theta = -1 * rad_theta * (180/pi);
        ctheta = cosd(deg_theta);  stheta = sind(deg_theta);

        Rmatrix = [ctheta, -1.*stheta;...
                   stheta,     ctheta];
        rotatedData = originalData*Rmatrix; 
        %assumption: rotate all the datas from the original base to the
        %base where the original x becomes alignmentVector

    else    % 3D rotation...        
        [rad_theta, rad_phi, rho] = cart2sph(alignmentVector(1), alignmentVector(2), alignmentVector(3));
        rad_theta = rad_theta * -1; 
        deg_theta = rad_theta * (180/pi);
        deg_phi = rad_phi * (180/pi); 
        ctheta = cosd(deg_theta);  stheta = sind(deg_theta); %MM : is it more accurate??
        Rz = [ctheta,   -1.*stheta,     0;...
              stheta,       ctheta,     0;...
              0,                 0,     1];                  %% First rotate as per theta around the Z axis
        rotatedData = originalData*Rz;

        [rotX, rotY, rotZ] = sph2cart(-1* (rad_theta+(pi/2)), 0, 1);          %% Second rotation corresponding to phi
        %assuming alignmentVector is the x for the new base, then the
        %hereabove argument corresponds to the y (z inversed)
        %the hereabove output = newX(in base 0) vectorial product -z(in base0)
        rotationAxis = [rotX, rotY, rotZ];
        u = rotationAxis(:)/norm(rotationAxis);        %% Code extract from rotate.m from MATLAB
        cosPhi = cosd(deg_phi);
        sinPhi = sind(deg_phi);
        invCosPhi = 1 - cosPhi;
        x = u(1);
        y = u(2);
        z = u(3);
        Rmatrix = [cosPhi+x^2*invCosPhi        x*y*invCosPhi-z*sinPhi     x*z*invCosPhi+y*sinPhi; ...
                   x*y*invCosPhi+z*sinPhi      cosPhi+y^2*invCosPhi       y*z*invCosPhi-x*sinPhi; ...
                   x*z*invCosPhi-y*sinPhi      y*z*invCosPhi+x*sinPhi     cosPhi+z^2*invCosPhi]';

        rotatedData = rotatedData*Rmatrix;        
    end
```

I end up getting:
[image: that ugly plot]

while I would like to conserve both intermediate plots containing the interp arrow:
[image: the interp arrow]

and the text on flashy white background:
[image: the text on flashy white background]

**So there are actually two questions:**

**1) Why calling my text tick disables the interp effect (varying color from blue to yellow) ?**

**2) How can I keep the camlight without enlightening my tick box? (i.e while keeping its background white)**

Basically one should only need to look at the two first snippets, the later 2 ones are useless for my issue.

By thanking you a lot!

Comment: your 3d text object is a surface with `Facecolor` as `texturemap`, the `CData` are `uint8` , while the 3d arrow is a surface where `CData` are `double` and `Facecolor` is `interp`. I don't think these 2 types of `CData` interpretation is compatible on the same figure/axes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Place it in another `axes`

As I said in comment, you have 2 graphic objects in the same `axes` which have to interpret their `CData` in a completely different manner.

The first options I looked for was to modify one of the `arrow3d` or `rotateAxisTicks` so their graphic objects would be "compatible" (in the way the color data are interpolated on an axes), but it would be quite intensive and the aspect of the 3d text would have to be constantly monitored/adjusted for any other change in the figure.

So the easiest option is a classic MATLAB hack ... place your graphic objects in different containers (different `axes`), then superimpose them on a figure, and match some properties (limits, view, etc ...) so they appear to be only one.

Here it goes:

```
%% Draw your main arrow in the main figure
mainfig = figure ;
ax1     = axes ;
arrow = arrow3D([0 0 0], [1 1 1], 'r', 0.8, 0.2, 1.5);
set(arrow, 'EdgeColor', 'interp', 'FaceColor', 'interp');
camlight headlight

%% Draw your text in a temporary figure
tempfig = figure ;
ax2 = axes ;
surfaceHandle = rotateAxisTicks('lol','r',10,-0.3,0.5,0.5,1,1,1,0);
camlight headlight
%material(surfaceHandle,'default') %doesn't work
%surfaceHandle1.FaceLighting = 'none' %doesn't work

%% Prepare and set matching limits
xl = [ax1.XLim ; ax2.XLim] ;
xl = [min(xl(:,1)) , max(xl(:,2))] ;
yl = [ax1.YLim ; ax2.YLim] ;
yl = [min(yl(:,1)) , max(yl(:,2))] ;
zl = [ax1.ZLim ; ax2.ZLim] ;
zl = [min(zl(:,1)) , max(zl(:,2))] ;

hax = [ax1;ax2] ;
set(hax,'XLim',xl,'YLim',yl,'ZLim',zl)

% Adjust the view to be sure
ax2.View = ax1.View ;

%% Remove secondary axes background, then move it to main figure
ax2.Visible = 'off' ;   
ax2.Parent = mainfig ;
delete(tempfig)

%% link the view between axes
hl = linkprop( hax , 'View' ) ;
% or link even more properties at once
% hl = linkprop( hax , 'View' , 'XLim','YLim','ZLim') ;
```

Which gives you:

[image: 3d arrow]

---

**note**: Your 3d arrow is also made up of 2 different graphic objects (2x `surf` and 2x `patch`). The 2 patches are not rendered when you set the `interp` mode. You should modify the `arrow3d` function to either (a) changes the `patch` objects to `surf` so everything is the same type and compatible, or (b) remove them completely from the function (if they are not rendered they are only annoying ... triggering warnings everywhere).

---

**edit**

And here is the modified code for `arrow3d.m`. I changed it so the output is now only one surface object, easier to assign properties and no danger of mismatch between `patch` and `surf`. I also simplified it, removed a few bits that were not necessary, and reduced the total number of points necessary for the surface.

With this you get the bottom of the stem and the under-cone:

```
function arrowHandle = arrow3D(pos, deltaValues, colorCode, stemRatio, cylRad )

% arrowHandle = arrow3D(pos, deltaValues, colorCode, stemRatio) %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% 
%     Used to plot a single 3D arrow with a cylindrical stem and cone arrowhead
%     pos = [X,Y,Z] - spatial location of the starting point of the arrow (end of stem)
%     deltaValues = [QX,QY,QZ] - delta parameters denoting the magnitude of the arrow along the x,y,z-axes (relative to 'pos')
%     colorCode - Color parameters as per the 'surf' command.  For example, 'r', 'red', [1 0 0] are all examples of a red-colored arrow
%     stemRatio - The ratio of the length of the stem in proportion to the arrowhead.  For example, a call of:
%                 arrow3D([0,0,0], [100,0,0] , 'r', 0.82) will produce a red arrow of magnitude 100, with the arrowstem spanning a distance
%                 of 82 (note 0.82 ratio of length 100) while the arrowhead (cone) spans 18.  
% 
%     Example:
%       arrow3D([0,0,0], [4,3,7]);  %---- arrow with default parameters
%       axis equal;
% 
%    Author: Shawn Arseneau
%    Created: September 14, 2006
%    Updated: September 18, 2006
%
%    Updated: December 20, 2018
%       Tlab - refactored to have only one surface object as ouput
% 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    if nargin<2 || nargin>6    
        error('Incorrect number of inputs to arrow3D');     
    end
    if numel(pos)~=3 || numel(deltaValues)~=3
        error('pos and/or deltaValues is incorrect dimensions (should be three)');
    end
    if nargin<3                 
        colorCode = 'interp';                               
    end
    if nargin<4                 
        stemRatio = 0.75;                                   
    end    
    Ncol = 21 ; % default number of column for the "cylinder.m" function

    X = pos(1); %---- with this notation, there is no need to transpose if the user has chosen a row vs col vector
    Y = pos(2);
    Z = pos(3);

    [~, ~, srho] = cart2sph(deltaValues(1), deltaValues(2), deltaValues(3));  

    %******************************************* CYLINDER == STEM *********************************************
    cylinderRadius = cylRad;
    cylinderLength = srho*stemRatio;
    [CX,CY,CZ] = cylinder(cylinderRadius,Ncol-1);
    CZ = CZ.*cylinderLength;    %---- lengthen

     %******************************************* CONE == ARROWHEAD *********************************************
    coneLength = srho*(1-stemRatio);
    [coneX, coneY, coneZ] = cylinder([cylinderRadius*2 0],Ncol-1);  %---------- CONE 
    coneZ = coneZ.*coneLength;
    % Translate cone on top of the stem cylinder
    coneZ = coneZ + cylinderLength ;

    % now close the bottom and add the cone to the stem cylinder surface
    bottom = zeros(1,Ncol) ;
    CX = [ bottom ; CX ; coneX ] ;
    CY = [ bottom ; CY ; coneY ] ;
    CZ = [ bottom ; CZ ; coneZ ] ;

    Nrow = size(CX,1);


    %----- ROTATE
    %---- initial rotation to coincide with X-axis
    newEll = rotatePoints([0 0 -1], [CX(:), CY(:), CZ(:)]); %CX(:) actually reshape the 2xN matrices in a 2N vert vector, by vertically concatenating each column
    CX = reshape(newEll(:,1), Nrow, Ncol);
    CY = reshape(newEll(:,2), Nrow, Ncol);
    CZ = reshape(newEll(:,3), Nrow, Ncol);

    newEll = rotatePoints(deltaValues, [CX(:), CY(:), CZ(:)]);
    stemX = reshape(newEll(:,1), Nrow, Ncol);
    stemY = reshape(newEll(:,2), Nrow, Ncol);
    stemZ = reshape(newEll(:,3), Nrow, Ncol);

    %----- TRANSLATE
    stemX = stemX + X;
    stemY = stemY + Y;
    stemZ = stemZ + Z;

    %----- DISPLAY
    hStem = surf(stemX, stemY, stemZ, 'FaceColor', colorCode, 'EdgeColor', 'none');

    %----- DISPLAY
    if nargout==1   
        arrowHandle = hStem ; 
    end
```

Comment: I was going to suggest pretty much the same thing. +1.

Comment: Hi @Hoki thanks for your solution, I check and +1 it in a moment!

About the patches, I wasn't able to "integrate" the plane surfaces into the `surf` object, would you have an idea by any chance?

Comment: @mmmmm. Yes I have a solution but the code for `arrow3d` is quite old and not organized the way I would do it. I'll see if I can modify it quickly or if I have to rewrite it differently.

Comment: @mmmmm, done. Now you can have fully defined 3d arrows ;-)